# Bash builtin, OSx vs Linux

Tags: bash

I noticed that the printf builtin between OSx and Linux does not appear to behave the same. I was under the impression that a builtin is a builtin. This is not related to any specific issue I am having.  I just cant explain it.

## OSx

```
printf '%(+%s)T\n' -2
-bash: printf: `(': invalid format character
```

```
which printf
printf is a shell builtin
printf is /usr/bin/printf
```

## Linux

```
printf '%(+%s)T\n' -2
+1431027100
```

```
which printf
printf is a shell builtin
printf is /usr/bin/printf
```

Some info on how this was tested. On OSx I am using a version of bash installed via brew.

## OSx version

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.1)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

## Linux version

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Comment: Does `help printf` on OSX say the `%(fmt)T` format specification is supported? Perhaps bash was [compiled differently](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Optional-Features.html).

Comment: I strongly, **strongly** suspect that the bash your script is actually running with in OS X isn't the same as the one you're checking the version number for.

Comment: By the way, `which printf` means nothing. Use `type printf`.

Comment: `help printf` on my bash with native bash does not show the fmt syntax. It does on my Linux-box.. So there is a difference, but still, builtin vs builtin?

Comment: @edos; can you try using `\printf` instead of `printf`, to make sure it is not being overridden as mentioned..

Comment: @xeor, `echo $BASH_VERSION`, rather than `bash --version`, to check the version on each; that will check your **currently running** version, rather than checking which version is first in your current PATH.

Comment: By the way, I can say that the latest version of bash shipped by MacPorts **definitely** supports `printf %()T`; I use this feature myself, for scripts that have users on Mac OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%()T` is a recent addition in bash 4.x; OS X ships bash 3.2 (and is not expected to ever upgrade to 4.x, as Apple refuses to ship software licensed GPLv3).

---

If `bash --version` is telling you that your OS X system has bash 4, this is probably a question of checking the version of bash in the PATH, vs the version in `/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/bash` (whichever is used for your script's shebang, or your user account's configured shell).

To check your current version of bash, don't use `bash --version` (which tells you the version of *the first bash interpreter in the PATH*, not the version of *the current interpreter*); instead, use:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

---

If you want to be sure your script uses the first bash interpreter in the PATH (which, if you installed a newer bash than the one Apple provided -- as with [macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) -- is presumably what you want), use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, not `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks this was bash --version fooling me. $BASH_VERSION was indeed v3.  I simply needed to point iterm correctly in preferences.  Under Profiles --> General --> Command and add "/usr/local/bin/bash -l".  All is well now.